# rxjs zip is not lazy?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, rxjs

I 've removed the boilerplate to get to the point

`// a.js`

```js
// My observables from stream and event
this.a = Rx.Node.fromStream(this.aStream());
this.itemSource = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(ee, 'addItem');

// Zip 'em
this.itemcombo = Rx.Observable.zip(this.a, this.itemSource, function (s1, s2) {
    return {item: s2, a: s1.toString()};
});

// Streams the lowercase alphabet
rb.prototype.aStream = function aStream() {
var rs = Readable();

var c = 97;
rs._read = function () {
    rs.push(String.fromCharCode(c++));
    console.log('Hit!');
    if (c > 'z'.charCodeAt(0)) {
        rs.push(null);
    }
};

return rs;
};
```

`// b.js` (requires the module exported above)

```
rb.enqueue('a'); // The method simply does an ee.emit('addItem', ...)  in the module to trigger the itemSource observable
```

**What I expected to see:**

`{item: 'a', a: 'a'}` printed in the console

**What happened:**

`Hit!` was printed 24 times before `{item: 'a', a: 'a'}`. This means that `zip` took all the values from `aStream`, buffered them and then did what it was supposed to do.

How do I get the same functionality `zip` offers but lazily? My goal is to use an infinite stream/observable and zip it with a finite (async) one.

**Edit**

See/Edit it via runnable: [RX Zip test](http://runnable.com/U_3c994wlwQ2Z73u/so-q-rx-zip-for-node-js-and-hello-world) **Edit 2** Code updated based on answer -> no output now.

Comment: Please add back the boilerplate and simplify the example.

Comment: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html

Comment: @DaveSexton See: http://pastebin.com/mnc82KuV and http://pastebin.com/8HxURWYc for a copy/paste/run version - thanks! I don't think the example can be simplified more. It 's 2 streams and the zip function. I 've included the stream I used for reference, it could have been left out, it 's safe to ignore that part but thought it may be useful.

Comment: @DaveSexton See my edit for a click & run web version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` is indeed lazy.  It just subscribes to `a` and `b` and does its work whenever either produces a new value.

Your problem is that `fromStream` is emitting all of its values synchronously as soon as `zip` subscribes to it.  This is happening because your custom `Readable` is constantly saying "There is more data available!"

Make your `Readable` asynchronous and you'll get the desired behavior.

Try something like this (untested)

```js
var rs = Readable();
var subscription = null;
rs._read = function () {
    if (!subscription) {
        // produce the values once per second
        subscription = Rx.Observable
            .generateWithRelativeTime(
                97, // start value
                function (c) { return c > 'z'.charCodeAt(0); }, // end condition
                function (c) { return c + 1; }, // step function
                function (c) { return String.fromCharCode(c); }, // result selector
                function () { return 1000; }) // 1000ms between values
            .subscribe(
                function (s) {
                    rs.push(s);
                    console.log("Hit!");
                },
                function (error) { rs.push(null); },
                function () { rs.push(null); });
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have updated the runnable fiddle to use your code, it simply outputs "Completed" and nothing else happens now. Also, even if we fix this by modifying this specific stream internally, my question is, is there a way to take any arbitrary stream and make it not overflow `zip` (so that I can use that pattern in any project)?

Comment: I am accepting this answer. After learning a bit more about Reactive Programming, I think I need to refactor my approach.